# htcondor: can a python executable started via condor_submit access all the values of its condor descriptors?

Tags: python, htcondor

Here a trivial submission file:

```
executable = /path/to/myexecutable
error = test.err
output = test.out
log = test.log
request_memory = 1024
request_cpus = 1
queue
```

`myexecutable` is a python executable

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                             

import htcondor

# here some code that retrieves the 
# value of a descriptor, e.g. 1024 for 'request_memory'
```

Once the executable started by condor (e.g. via condor_submit) is there some ways to retrieve the values of the descriptors provided in the submission file ? (including the values of the expanded macros, so directly parsing the file would not do it)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using the `htcondor` python bindings inside of an executable.

I think the most straightforward is to use the [`arguments` command in the submit file](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man-pages/condor_submit.html#:%7E:text=arguments%20%3D%20%3Cargument_list%3E) to pass information from the submit file to the executable.

Here is how to pass the value of `request_memory` in your example. The submit file:

```
executable = /path/to/myexecutable
arguments = $(request_memory)
error = test.err
output = test.out
log = test.log
request_memory = 1024
request_cpus = 1
queue
```

The executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                             

import sys

# catch the argument
my_memory = sys.argv[1]

# Value of 'my_memory' will match the 'request_memory' from the submit file
print(my_memory)
```

Note that the variable name itself (`request_memory`) is not passed, only its value, so you need to make sure the order of your arguments in the submit file matches the order you in which you catch the arguments.

***Update:*** Realized the title was asking for all descriptors.

I don't recommend this, but in the executable's directory should be a file `.job.ad` that should contain all of that job's ClassAds that existed at the start of the job execution.

The reason I don't recommend it is that the submit descriptors do not necessarily match the name of their corresponding ClassAd. For your example, the submit descriptor `request_memory` corresponds to the ClassAd `RequestMemory`.

For your example, this looks like

```
>>> with open('.job.ad', 'r') as f:
...    for line in f.readlines():
...        if 'RequestMemory' in line:
...            print(line)
RequestMemory = 1024
```